# How to measure code coverage with Selenium

Tags: selenium, jboss-arquillian, jacoco, ar.drone

My project is composed by a EJB module and a Web module.

The EJB module uses Arquillian with Persistence extension to run integration tests. Arquillian starts up a managed Jboss7, setup the database, run the tests and then shuts down Jboss. I have JaCoCo Maven Plugin configured to generated code coverage reports for those tests and everything is working perfectly - reports are created and exported to a sonar server.

The Web module uses Arquillian with Drone/Graphene extensions to run Selenium tests. So, during my CI build, Arquillian starts a Jboss7, starts firefox and run the Selenium test suites automatically. Here is where I'm having troubles... All the tests run just fine, however JaCoCo reports are not being generated for this module.

Both modules share a common root pom, here is the relevant bit of this pom:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <version.joda.time>2.1</version.joda.time>
        <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
        <version.mockito>1.9.5</version.mockito>
        <version.jacoco>0.6.0.201210061924</version.jacoco>
        <version.arquillian.jacoco>1.0.0.Alpha5</version.arquillian.jacoco>
        <version.arquillian.persistence>1.0.0.Alpha6</version.arquillian.persistence>
        <version.commons.collections>3.2.1</version.commons.collections>
        <version.guava.testlib>14.0.1</version.guava.testlib>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${version.joda.time}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mockito}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
            <version>${version.guava.testlib}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${version.commons.collections}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.Alpha2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jacoco}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${failsafe.argLine}</argLine>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jgitflow-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableFeatureVersions>true</enableFeatureVersions>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                                            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <!-- Ignore/Execute plugin execution -->
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                    <pluginExecutions>
                                        <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                                        <pluginExecution>
                                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                                <goals>
                                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <action>
                                                <execute />
                                            </action>
                                        </pluginExecution>
                                    </pluginExecutions>
                                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-jacoco</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <version>${version.arquillian.jacoco}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jacoco}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.arquillian.persistence}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Why would you get a test coverage for Selenium tests?! These are UI tests not unit tests!

Comment: Unit tests are not the only kind of tests that deserve having code coverage reports, integration test coverage is also useful information. This is not only my opinion, [sonar has tools to separate integration test coverage from unit test coverage](http://www.sonarqube.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/).

Comment: I agree with that too. But Selenium Tests just tests the UI through a web browser. What kind of code coverage do you expect to collect?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong here, but it looks like you've running into a problem with the Jacoco and Failsafe plugins, like the one discussed [here](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/40). Your best bet is to ask in the [Jacoco discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jacoco), or to post the output of your `mvn` command with the `-X` flag.

Comment: Laurent, when the user clicks a button or submits a form, business methods are called on my Action layer and propagated all the way to the Data Access layer. That is the code I want to collect information about.

Comment: Vineet, I have posted [this question on the Arquillian forum](https://community.jboss.org/message/835727?et=watches.email.thread#835727), people there are being very helpful. The thing is that Drone tests have to be annotated with `@RunAsClient`, so they run in a "black-box" manner (no access to internals, therefore no in-container extensions).

Comment: @Felipe, that did cross my mind, but something is fishy. I know, because I raised [ARQ-560](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-560), and yet you say that the Jacoco+Maven plugins work for your integration tests of EJB module on managed AS7. I don't know how that coverage data is correct since 1. you're not starting AS7 with the Jacoco agent, and 2. there is nothing in your test suite to collect the coverage data from AS7, unless I missed somehthing. I think you should revisit your setup, and to get coverage, you may want to see [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/822951#822951).

Comment: I can't explain why, but it works on the EJB module. [this link](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) states that if you use JaCoCo maven plugin "you don't have to care about the agent and its options directly. This is transparently handled by the them (the plugin)."

Comment: @FelipeReis no that agent doesn't help; it only instruments the JVM running Surefire/Failsafe. The AS7 JVM is not configured to use that agent. That's why there is a [Jacoco extension for Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/modules/jacoco-extension/) that instruments your ShrinkWrap deployment before the container receives it & before tests are run; your POM does not use this module. I think your coverage data is for the code running in the Surefire/Failsafe JVM and not for managed AS7 that does not even know of Jacoco. That is why I recommend that you review your entire test suite setup.